# How to count occurrences of several strings per row in a data frame in R

Tags: r, string, count

i have a question for which I thought I found a solution but if I double checked by hand I got numbers. I searched in other quotes but couldn't get exactly what I am looking for.

I have a dataframe with pharmaceutical agents. Each row is a subject and up to 20 columns store an agent each.Then I have a list of agents that can be clustered for one purpose. E.g. beta blockers. What I would like to do is iterate over each row to count if and how many e.g. beta blockers or statins a subject is taking.

I have tried with:

```
BETA = c("METOPROLOL", "BISOPROLOL", "NEBILET", "METOHEXAL", "SOTALEX",
         "QUERTO", "NEBIVOLOL", "CARVEDILOL", "METOPROLOLSUCCINAT", "BELOC")
for (i in 1:202) {
  dat$betablock[i] <- sum(str_count(meds[i,], BETA ))
}
```

I don't get a warning but it doesn't count the correct number of occurrences.

Here is some sample data:

```
       Med1         Med2       Med3          Med4            Med5          Med6       Med7         Med8        Med9     Med10      Med11    Med12    Med13    Med14      Med15
1  AMLODIPIN     RAMIPRIL METOPROLOL                                                                                                                                           
2     PLAVIX  SIMVASTATIN MIRTAZAPIN                                                                                                                                           
3 BISOPROLOL    AMLODIPIN        ASS     VALSARTAN    CHLORALDURAT     Doxozosin TAMSULOSIN     CIPRAMIL                                                                       
4        ASS    ENALAPRIL L-THYROXIN       LITALIR         LITALIR     AMLODIPIN  CETIRIZIN          HCT        NACL    CARMEN PROTEIN 88 NOVALGIN                             
5        ASS ATORVASTATIN    FOSAMAX       CALCIUM        PANTOZOL NOVAMINSULFON                                                                                               
6        ASS      FRAGMIN  TORASEMID SPIRONOLACTON LORZAAR PROTECT       VESIKUR  ROCALTROL ATORVASTATIN PREDNISOLON LACTULOSE MIRTAZAPIN   LANTUS ACTRAPID PANTOZOL SALBUTAMOL
          Med16 Med17 Med18 Med19 Med20
1                                      
2                                      
3                                      
4                                      
5                                      
6 AMPHO MORONAL
```

As you can see in the first row third column the string 'METOPROLOL' is listed. But when I call the result of my for loop for the first subject it results '0'.

```
> dat$betablock[1]
[1] 0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may need to loop the other way or use `paste(BETA, collapse = "|")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP has *multiple* lists of agents that can be clustered for one purpose *not just one list* of beta blockers. The OP mentions statins, e.g. The OP wants to count how many different agents belonging to each cluster are being taken by each subject. The counts for each agent cluster are to be appended to each row.

I suggest to compute the sums *for all clusters at once* rather than to do this manually list by list.

For this, we first need to set-up a data frame with the clustering:

```
cluster
```

> ```
>     Purpose              Agent
>  1:    BETA         METOPROLOL
>  2:    BETA         BISOPROLOL
>  3:    BETA            NEBILET
>  4:    BETA          METOHEXAL
>  5:    BETA            SOTALEX
>  6:    BETA             QUERTO
>  7:    BETA          NEBIVOLOL
>  8:    BETA         CARVEDILOL
>  9:    BETA METOPROLOLSUCCINAT
> 10:    BETA              BELOC
> 11:  STATIN       ATORVASTATIN
> 12:  STATIN        SIMVASTATIN
> 13:  STATIN         LOVASTATIN
> 14:  STATIN        PRAVASTATIN
> 15:  STATIN        FLUVASTATIN
> 16:  STATIN         PITAVASTIN
> ```

`cluster` can be created, e.g., by

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
cluster <- list(
  BETA = c("METOPROLOL", "BISOPROLOL", "NEBILET", "METOHEXAL", "SOTALEX",
           "QUERTO", "NEBIVOLOL", "CARVEDILOL", "METOPROLOLSUCCINAT", "BELOC"),
  STATIN = c("ATORVASTATIN", "SIMVASTATIN", "LOVASTATIN", "PRAVASTATIN", 
           "FLUVASTATIN", "PITAVASTIN")
  ) %>% 
  lapply(data.table) %>% 
  rbindlist(idcol = "Purpose") %>% 
  setnames("V1", "Agent")
```

For counting the occurrences, we need to join or merge this table with the list of agents each subject is taking `dat` after `dat` has been reshaped from wide to long format.

While data in spreadsheet-style wide format, i.e., with one row per subject and many columns, are often suitable for data entry and inspection the database-style long format is often more suitable for data processing.

```
taken <- melt(setDT(dat)[, ID := .I], "ID", value.name = "Agent", na.rm = TRUE)[
  Agent != ""][
    , Agent := toupper(Agent)][]
```

> ```
>     ID variable           Agent
>  1:  1     Med1       AMLODIPIN
>  2:  2     Med1          PLAVIX
>  3:  3     Med1      BISOPROLOL
>  4:  4     Med1             ASS
>  5:  5     Med1             ASS
>  6:  6     Med1             ASS
>  7:  1     Med2        RAMIPRIL
>  8:  2     Med2     SIMVASTATIN
>  9:  3     Med2       AMLODIPIN
> 10:  4     Med2       ENALAPRIL
> 11:  5     Med2    ATORVASTATIN
> 12:  6     Med2         FRAGMIN
> 13:  1     Med3      METOPROLOL
> 14:  2     Med3      MIRTAZAPIN
> 15:  3     Med3             ASS
> 16:  4     Med3      L-THYROXIN
> 17:  5     Med3         FOSAMAX
> 18:  6     Med3       TORASEMID
> 19:  3     Med4       VALSARTAN
> 20:  4     Med4         LITALIR
> 21:  5     Med4         CALCIUM
> 22:  6     Med4   SPIRONOLACTON
> 23:  3     Med5    CHLORALDURAT
> 24:  4     Med5         LITALIR
> 25:  5     Med5        PANTOZOL
> 26:  6     Med5 LORZAAR PROTECT
> 27:  3     Med6       DOXOZOSIN
> 28:  4     Med6       AMLODIPIN
> 29:  5     Med6   NOVAMINSULFON
> 30:  6     Med6         VESIKUR
> 31:  3     Med7      TAMSULOSIN
> 32:  4     Med7       CETIRIZIN
> 33:  6     Med7       ROCALTROL
> 34:  3     Med8        CIPRAMIL
> 35:  4     Med8             HCT
> 36:  6     Med8    ATORVASTATIN
> 37:  4     Med9            NACL
> 38:  6     Med9     PREDNISOLON
> 39:  4    Med10          CARMEN
> 40:  6    Med10       LACTULOSE
> 41:  4    Med11      PROTEIN 88
> 42:  6    Med11      MIRTAZAPIN
> 43:  4    Med12        NOVALGIN
> 44:  6    Med12          LANTUS
> 45:  6    Med13        ACTRAPID
> 46:  6    Med14        PANTOZOL
> 47:  6    Med15      SALBUTAMOL
> 48:  6    Med16   AMPHO MORONAL
>     ID variable           Agent
> ```

`dat` is modified by appending a row number which identifies each subject, then it is reshaped to long format using `melt()`. Missing or empty entries are removed and agent names are converted to uppercase for consistency.

**Edit** In long format it is also easy to check for duplicate agents per subject

```
taken[duplicated(taken, by = c("ID", "Agent"))]
```

> ```
>    ID variable   Agent
> 1:  4     Med5 LITALIR
> ```

and remove the duplicates:

```
taken <- unique(taken, by = c("ID", "Agent"))
```

The final step creates what I believe is the expected result:

> ```
>    ID BETA STATIN       Med1         Med2       Med3          Med4            Med5          Med6       Med7         Med8
> 1:  1    1      0  AMLODIPIN     RAMIPRIL METOPROLOL                                                                    
> 2:  2    0      1     PLAVIX  SIMVASTATIN MIRTAZAPIN                                                                    
> 3:  3    1      0 BISOPROLOL    AMLODIPIN        ASS     VALSARTAN    CHLORALDURAT     Doxozosin TAMSULOSIN     CIPRAMIL
> 4:  4    0      0        ASS    ENALAPRIL L-THYROXIN       LITALIR         LITALIR     AMLODIPIN  CETIRIZIN          HCT
> 5:  5    0      1        ASS ATORVASTATIN    FOSAMAX       CALCIUM        PANTOZOL NOVAMINSULFON                        
> 6:  6    0      1        ASS      FRAGMIN  TORASEMID SPIRONOLACTON LORZAAR PROTECT       VESIKUR  ROCALTROL ATORVASTATIN
> ```

Pleae, note the additional columns with the counts by cluster (Due to limited space not all columns of the result are shown here). This is created by

```
cluster[taken, on = .(Agent)][
  , dcast(.SD, ID ~ Purpose, length)][
    dat, on = "ID"][
      , "NA" := NULL][]
```

using the following operations:

1. Join `cluster` and `taken` to have `Purpose` appended
2. Reshape to wide format, one row per subject and one column per purpose, thereby counting the number of occurrences
3. Join this result result with the original data `dat`
4. Remove the superfluous column of NA counts

#### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(Med1 = c("AMLODIPIN", "PLAVIX", "BISOPROLOL", 
"ASS", "ASS", "ASS"), Med2 = c("RAMIPRIL", "SIMVASTATIN", "AMLODIPIN", 
"ENALAPRIL", "ATORVASTATIN", "FRAGMIN"), Med3 = c("METOPROLOL", 
"MIRTAZAPIN", "ASS", "L-THYROXIN", "FOSAMAX", "TORASEMID"), Med4 = c("", 
"", "VALSARTAN", "LITALIR", "CALCIUM", "SPIRONOLACTON"), Med5 = c("", 
"", "CHLORALDURAT", "LITALIR", "PANTOZOL", "LORZAAR PROTECT"), 
    Med6 = c("", "", "Doxozosin", "AMLODIPIN", "NOVAMINSULFON", 
    "VESIKUR"), Med7 = c("", "", "TAMSULOSIN", "CETIRIZIN", "", 
    "ROCALTROL"), Med8 = c("", "", "CIPRAMIL", "HCT", "", "ATORVASTATIN"
    ), Med9 = c("", "", "", "NACL", "", "PREDNISOLON"), Med10 = c("", 
    "", "", "CARMEN", "", "LACTULOSE"), Med11 = c("", "", "", 
    "PROTEIN 88", "", "MIRTAZAPIN"), Med12 = c("", "", "", "NOVALGIN", 
    "", "LANTUS"), Med13 = c("", "", "", "", "", "ACTRAPID"), 
    Med14 = c("", "", "", "", "", "PANTOZOL"), Med15 = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", "SALBUTAMOL"), Med16 = c("", "", "", "", 
    "", "AMPHO MORONAL")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: This is so absolutely what I wanted to have in the end. Beautiful direct way. Only, I have to admit that my R knowledge is not extensive enough to understand your code. But thank you very much. I noticed that there are some duplettes in some of the subjects. Is there a way to implement checking for duplettes on the original data 'dat'? Also I noticed when I add more lists of agents after the sixth list the name of the list is not included in the file 'cluster' any more. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: By default, `print()`  will limit the number of rows displayed on screen. You may check the completeness either by looking at the last rows with `tail(cluster)` or by counting the number of agents in each group `cluster[, .N, by = Purpose]`.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the data about pharamcueticals is in a data.frame `agents`. Translate the elements of `agents` into logical values, with `TRUE` present when the element is in `BETA`

```
found = agents     # copy agents...
found[] = unlist(agents) %in% BETA
```

Then the number of beta blockers in each row (subject) are

```
rowSums(found)
```

As a toy example, here are some agents and beta blockers

```
agents = data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = c("b", "c", "d"))
beta = c("a", "b")
```

and the results of the computation

```
> agents
  x y
1 a b
2 b c
3 c d
> found = agents
> found[] = unlist(agents) %in% beta
> found
      x     y
1  TRUE  TRUE
2  TRUE FALSE
3 FALSE FALSE
> rowSums(found)
[1] 2 1 0
> agents$beta_blockers = rowSums(found)
> agents
  x y beta_blockers
1 a b             2
2 b c             1
3 c d             0
```

This use of `%in%` performs an exact match -- the terms in `agents` are matched exactly to the terms in `beta`. This seems to be what the problem calls for. The original code and other solutions aim for partial match, e.g., if a row had entries "a", "aa", and "ab" then the code would compute

```
> stringr::str_count(c("a", "aa", "ab"), "a")
[1] 1 2 1
```

with `sum(.)` equal to 4, whereas there is only one occurrence of "a" so the correct answer is 1. Also, the code is susceptible to the default use of factors to represent columns in a data.frame, and apparently `stringr` does not convert factors to character vectors before doing the comparison

```
> agents = data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = c("b", "c", "d")
> stringr::str_count(agents[1,], c("a", "b"))
[1] 0 0
> agents = data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = c("b", "c", "d"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> stringr::str_count(agents[1,], c("a", "b"))
[1] 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any suggestions why my code didn't work?

Comment: @Torsten I added some comments at the end about what the issue with your approach might have been.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

In the following code, you can calculate the sum of each beta blockers in `BETA` and the sum of all beta blockers for each individual (row).

```r
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(
  Med1 = c("AMLODIPIN", "PLAVIX", "BISOPROLOL", "ASS", "ASS", "ASS"), 
  Med2 = c("RAMIPRIL", "SIMVASTATIN", "AMLODIPIN","ENALAPRIL", "ATORVASTATIN", "FRAGMIN"), 
  Med3 = c("METOPROLOL", "MIRTAZAPIN", "ASS", "L-THYROXIN", "FOSAMAX", "TORASEMID"), 
  Med4 = c("BISOPROLOL", "CARVEDILOL", "VALSARTAN", "LITALIR", "CALCIUM", "SPIRONOLACTON")
  ) 
BETA <- c("METOPROLOL", "BISOPROLOL", "NEBILET", "METOHEXAL", "SOTALEX",
         "QUERTO", "NEBIVOLOL", "CARVEDILOL", "METOPROLOLSUCCINAT", "BELOC")
df$med_all <- paste(df$Med1, df$Med2, df$Med3, df$Med4, sep = ", ")
# get sum of each of the beta blockers in BETA 
sapply(BETA, function(x) sum(str_count(df$med_all, c(x))))
#>         METOPROLOL         BISOPROLOL            NEBILET          METOHEXAL 
#>                  1                  2                  0                  0 
#>            SOTALEX             QUERTO          NEBIVOLOL         CARVEDILOL 
#>                  0                  0                  0                  1 
#> METOPROLOLSUCCINAT              BELOC 
#>                  0                  0
# get sum of all blockers for each individual 
df1<-sapply(BETA, function(x) str_count(df$med_all, c(x)))
rowSums(df1)
#> [1] 2 1 1 0 0 0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>